# Embedding Layer on unseen data

Tags: deep-learning, categorical-data, embeddings

Let's say we have a categorical variables with 5 different categories (levels). I train and get a good model based on this dataset using embedding layer with, say, 3 embedding size and with some numerical features. However, how embedding layer reacts when we have an unseen data with an additional category (level) of this particular categorical variable?

Comment: The actual behavior might depend on which implementation you're using.  Keras, e.g., requires integer-encoded levels, so your new levels will need to be mapped somewhere, and if they are mapped outside the original range you will get an error.  There's probably not a _right_ way to do this, as the model doesn't know anything about the new level, but you can review strategies for new categorical levels in any other model type, including training on an "other" level or imputing as some sort of average.

Comment: Alright, these were exactly what I was thinking. Level mismatch is a huge trouble here obviously. I was just checking any additional steps in the field NLP but could not come up with anything so I just wanted ask! Thank you!